# Get a notification when a file is modified

Tags: windows, notifications

I'd like to have a notification when a simple .txt, which is on my NAS, is modified by someone.
The problem is that I'm definitely not good enough in c++ to make it by myself.
If I could get some help it would be nice.
Thanks

Comment: You should tell us what you have tried, we are not working for you, only helping you

Comment: The point is, I have no idea of how I'm supposed to do this, and I didn't find any tutorial for my problem

Comment: This is a website for programmers, who investigate their problem first. Check the Windows API on Microsoft.com, try VB if C++ is not your thing.

Comment: So I’ve been thinking, I know much more Python than C++, so I should be able to make the graphics of the popup, but I don’t if it’s possible to make it appear whenever a given file, like the program is running and testing in backgroung, from the start to the shutdown of the pc

Comment: By the way, thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from time import sleep

text = open(r"\\WDMYCLOUD\","r")
text = text.read()
compare = open(r"\\WDMYCLOUD\","r")
compare = compare.read()

while True:
    if(compare != text):
        toaster = ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast(**)
    text = open(r"\\WDMYCLOUD\","r")
    text = text.read()

sleep(3600)
compare = open(r"\\WDMYCLOUD\","r")
compare = compare.read()
```

So here's my code to my notifications, it perfectly works.
Inside the show_toast, ** replace the text I wanted to display.
What I'd like to do, is when I click on the notification, it opens the targeted file, text.txt for example. Is there any way to do that ?